# Can I specify section attribute to compound literals?

Tags: gcc, attributes, compound-literals

With GCC, I can do this:

```
typedef struct {
    char a;
    int n;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct ms __attribute__((section("MySection"))) = {'x', 33};
MyStruct *pms = &ms;
```

But when I use compound literal as follows, GCC complains **warning: 'section' attribute does not apply to types [-Wattributes]**.

```
typedef struct {
    char a;
    int n;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct *pms = &(MyStruct __attribute__((section("MySection")))){'x', 33};
```

Is there any way to get by? Thank you.